# Ruby on Rails: colon in commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rake

When working with ruby on rails, it is common to use terminal commands like `rake db:migrate` or `rails g devise:install`. But what exactly does the `:` in these commands mean? In `rake db:migrate` is `migrate` a parameter or something else?

Comment: Look inside a Rakefile, and you will see rake tasks organized into namespaces and tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Philip explained in his answer when using rake the colon defines the seperator between namespaces/tasks

When using `rails g(enerate)` it's basically the same. The difference is that Rails generators aren't defined with rake's DSL, instead they're classes.

But to answer your initial Questions: The Colon works as seperator, in both cases, that's it.

In the code the only thing what it's important for is splitting up the string:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L124

You can find some more infos about generators and how to create your one ones (which definetley will help you understanding the mechanics behind it) in the official [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html)

//EDIT
Ok, let's take a closer look at the generator lookup process:

First of all there is [`Rails::Generators.invoke`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L152)

It receives the namespaces passed on the CLI and split's it up (using the colon)

```
  names = namespace.to_s.split(':')
```

then it get's the according class by passing the last part of the passed namespace (the actual generator name) and the remaining part joined with a colon again (the namespace path, in our case it's *devise*) to [`Rails::Generators::Base.find_by_namespace`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L124)

```
  if klass = find_by_namespace(names.pop, names.any? && names.join(':'))
```

This method again will join the base (namespace path) and name (generator name) and push it to an array:

```
lookups = []
lookups << "#{base}:#{name}"    if base
```

after that it calls [`Rails::Generators.lookup`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L272) which will lookup the classes to invoke for the called generator:

```
lookup(lookups)
```

which will again will call [`Rails::Generators.namepaces_to_paths`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L308)

There's no big magic in that method, it'll simply return an array of two possible source paths for the invoked generator in our case these two are "devise/install/install" and "devise/install".

Whereby those aren't the actual paths rails will check, they are only the part's of it that are depend on the namespace:generator construct.

The `lookup` method will now take those two, let's call them subpaths, and check for files to require at the following places:

1. rails/generators/devise/install/install_generator
2. generators/devise/install/install_generator
3. rails/generators/devise/install_generator
4. generators/devise/install_generator

in our case the second path is the desired file, rails require's it and through that the [`inherited`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/base.rb#L225) ([more about that callback](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback on [`Rails::Generators::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/base.rb) will get called since [`Devise::Generators::InstallGenerator`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/devise/install_generator.rb) inherits from it.

This will add the Class to the `subclasses` array of `Rails::Generators` which is mapped to an Hash which will have the format { namespace => klass } and so rails is finally able to get the desired Generator Class

[`klass = namespaces[namespace]`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L142)

and start it

[`klass.start(args, config)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb#L156)

Comment: That helps a lot. However I am still confused on how it works in the generate case. I've actually read this ruby on rails guide that you mentioned many times, but I still don't get how it works for the devise code that I showed Phillip. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of the colon as a namespace.  Somewhere within Rails there is a rake task file that looks similar to this:

```
namespace db
  task :migrate do...
    ....
  end
end
```

It's a way to group related tasks together and prevent them from colliding with other tasks.  This way you could potentially have devise:migrate, db:migrate, foobar:migrate, etc.

Comment: So foo:bar means namespace foo, task :bar?

Comment: Yes.  Keep in mind though, you can have nested namespaces as well.  Rake a:b:c:d is perfectly valid.

Comment: As for `rails g devise:install`, I am still a bit confused. 
`rails g devise [model_name]` runs the generator http://bit.ly/15bN3nt, but  `rails g devise:install` runs this other one http://bit.ly/1alZ8gM even though there are no tasks defined there. Sorry to bother you more with that.

Comment: Ah.  rails vs rake.  I'm not sure what the convention is for 'rails'.  I was talking about rake only.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. I mean for rails in general what exactly does foo:bar on the terminal mean?